# Underline multiple lines in single TextField - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

Looking to have a TextField which has multiple rows but also an underline for each row. When typing text it should continue to the next row without needing the return key.

Current:

```
TextField(
                    maxLines: 2,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 1.0,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

Current Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

this will work for you I guess

```
TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              minLines: 100,
              maxLines: 500,
              style: TextStyle(
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Notes.....',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              ),
            ),
```

If you'd still like to change the color or type or density of the underline use the `decorationStyle`,`decorationColor`, and `decorationThickness` properties.

Comment: Your solution is a different than what I am looking for. I want the underline to be present for maxLines and the length of the widget. Not just a decoration for text that has been entered.

Comment: wait i will give you some refrence of this

Comment: Sorry, but no I didn't get a solution. Ended up changing the UI design to resolve.